# converting string to byte

Tags: java, string, byte

I have a text field populated with bytes.
When i call the String s  = textfield.getText(); 
by default it is a string data type of the byte it returns. 
i want to get the actual byte in the text field as data type bytes. 
But if i do s.getbyte, i will convert the byte to a new byte. 
Please who can help me out here.

```
           //this gives me another bye than the one in the text field.
            String ss = new String(Textfield().getText().getBytes(), "UTF-8");

            //i want to get something like this
            byte [] b = Textfield().getText(); //without geting a new byte
            String ss = new String(Textfield().getText().getBytes(), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: What does the text field look like?

Comment: what do you mean by `a text field populated with bytes` ? a text field contains a String which is composed by characters which themselves can be represented by up to 2 bytes. Can you provide an example of what your text field contains and what is the expected result for that content?

Answer (score -1):

Just call `String#getBytes()` and always call `String#intern()` after the constructor the fill the new String into the Stringpool.

```
byte [] b = Textfield().getText().getBytes();
String ss = new String(Textfield().getText().getBytes(), "UTF-8").intern();
```

Comment: `intern()` has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: It hasn't but was general advice.